# Not able to append variable name and content as a string in file using powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, variables, window, append

## This is the code for creating file and append content into it.I want to print file content as it is return below.Please give some example how to print variable name with $ si

```
New-Item 2.bat -type file -force -value "'
$passwd='Umesh_Pithiya' `r`n
$pass=$passwd.substring(9) `r`n
$pass=$pass.substring(1,$pass.length-2) `r`n
$pass=convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force `r`n
"
```

## Output is like this

```
'
='Umesh_Pithiya' 

=.substring(9) 

=.substring(1,.length-2) 

=convertto-securestring  -asplaintext -force
```

## But I want content in file like this

```
$passwd='Umesh_Pithiya'
$pass=$passwd.substring(9)
$pass=$pass.substring(1,$pass.length-2)
$pass=convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'` instead of `"` to create a verbatim string. Construct it as a here-string `@''@` to avoid the single-quotes inside the text terminating the string:

```
New-Item 2.bat -type file -force -value @'
$passwd='Umesh_Pithiya' 
$pass=$passwd.substring(9) 
$pass=$pass.substring(1,$pass.length-2) 
$pass=convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force 
'@
```

Comment: doesn't `'` collide with the here string?

Comment: @4c74356b41 No, parser expects a newline + `'@` as the terminator

Comment: btw, I can't seem to find anything relevant, is there a difference between `@"` and `@'` here strings in PowerShell?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes, `@"` starts an *expandable* here-string (just like the difference in behavior between `"` and `'`, besides the fact that terminator is different so you don't need to escape the quotes themselves)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Paste this into your shell to see the difference: https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/4c7eceed0b8aeeeba4991e32340ba9ea

Comment: How to add new line at the end of every statement so poweshell can exceute it correctly?

Comment: For powershell to execute it, name it `2.ps1` rather than `2.bat`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [here string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx):

```
New-Item 2.bat -type file -force -value @'
$passwd='Umesh_Pithiya'
$pass=$passwd.substring(9)
$pass=$pass.substring(1,$pass.length-2)
$pass=convertto-securestring $pass -asplaintext -force
'@
```

Note that you don't need to escape the carriage return and line feeds now. Also, use the single quote to avoid variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks Sean,
It worked but whole content come in single line.
do you have any idea how to add new line at the end of every statement?